# How to access a value in a dictionary of a list and add it (counter)

Tags: python

so basically I have a list of numbers called numList. 
Ex. `[11,54,22,42,5,16,79,18,39]`

I also have a dictionary of lists dictionary. 
Ex. `{0:[10,20,0],1:[15,20,0],2:[20,30,0], 3:[30,90,0]}`.

My goal is to iterate through each number in numList, and iterate through each key in the dictionary and check if each number in numList is between the first two values of every key in dictionary. If the number is between the first two values of every key, then I want to add +1 to the third value of that key (hence why the third value of every key is 0).

so basically, Is 11 >= 10 and 11 <= 20? Yes, so +1. So now it's `{0:[10,20,1],1:[15,20,0],2:[20,30,0], 3:[30,90,0]}` and do this through every key.

So basically how do I add +1? And I am also getting the following errors:

```
if number >= dictionary.get(key,0) and number <= dictionary.get(key,1):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() >= list()
```

Code:

```
dictionary = dict(list)
for number in numList:
    for key in dictionary:
        if number >= dictionary.get(key,0) and number <= dictionary.get(key,1):
            print("testing") #add 1
```

Comment: I would expect `dictionary = dict(list)` to raise `TypeError` - presumably, `list` is not what it should be?

Comment: The problem seems to lie in ``if number >= dictionary.get(key,0)``

Comment: Jonrsharpe seems to be correct: You might be better off using defaultdict(list) which can be imported from collections.

Comment: @PeterLustig I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do, I think they have simply used `list` as a general variable name

Comment: oh god, even worse :)

Comment: sorry for using such a vague variable name lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) -- the second argument is actually the default value to be returned if the key is not present in the dictionary. In your case, it actually returns a list. What you want is something like:

```
if number >= dictionary[key][0] and number <= dictionary[key][1]:
    ...
```

Comment: I would second that. You need to access the first and second value of the list of each dictionary value. As YS-L has explained, get has different semantics than what you assumed.

Comment: Awesome! By this I was able to add counter by  `dictionary[key][2] += 1` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may be better to reorganize your dictionary. Try this instead:

```
table = {(10,20): 0, (15,20): 0, (20,30): 0, (30,90): 0}

for key in table:
    start,end = key
    if start <= num <= end:
        table[key] += 1
```

Remember that any time you use a dictionary whose keys are just integers, you may as well be using a list instead. Organize them so their keys are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary = {0:[10,20,0],1:[15,20,0],2:[20,30,0], 3:[30,90,0]}
list_numbers = [11,54,22,42,5,16,79,18,39]

for n in list_numbers:
    for value in dictionary.values():
        if value[0] < n < value[1]:
            value[2]+=1
```

Output:

```
print dictionary
```

> {0: [10, 20, 3], 1: [15, 20, 2], 2: [20, 30, 1], 3: [30, 90, 4]}

Comment: no reason to do `dict.items` if you're tossing away the key. use `dict.values`